# How to generate a 14 digit serial number in python?

Tags: python, digits, serial-number

How can I generate 14 digit serial numbers in python where the last for 4 digit will be **0001** the next will be **0002** ...... **0011** and so on? This is how I want the format of the number to be  **12101010010001** below is the breakdown of the format.

```
First three digits (121) = Local Govt. ID
4th & 5th digits (01) = Zonal ID
6th & 7th digits (01) = Area ID
8th to 10th digits (001) = CDA No.
Last four digits (0001) Property No.
```

Comment: You format is somewhat underspecified. What are the constraints on such a number compared to an arbitrary 14-digit number?

Comment: what have you tried so far?
`["{}{}{}{}{:04d}".format(LGI, ZID, AID, CDA, x) for x in range(1, 10000)]` as a general case, or just `["1210101001{:04d}".format(x) for x in range(1, 10000)]`

Comment: @phipsgabler I want the constraints of the number to be 14 digit long

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your response this will be as a general case like the example you gave` ["{}{}{}{}{:04d}".format(LGI, ZID, AID, CDA, x) for x in range(1, 10000)]` I am trying this out now

Comment: tom-karzes answer is excellent for the general case

Answer (score 3):

I would construct it as a string:

```
sn = "{:03}{:02}{:02}{:03}{:04}".format(121, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

This gives `sn` the value `'12101010010001'`, zero-padding the fields to the desired width.  If you want to convert the result to an integer (as opposed to leaving it as a string), just use `int(sn)`.